# The system cannot find the path specified error

Tags: npm, static

```
Error: The system cannot find the path specified.

    at notFoundError (C:\MGGIT\mysite\node_modules\cross-spawn\lib\enoent.js:11:11)
    at verifyENOENT (C:\MGGIT\mysite\node_modules\cross-spawn\lib\enoent.js:46:16)
    at ChildProcess.cp.emit (C:\MGGIT\mysite\node_modules\cross-spawn\lib\enoent.js:33:19)
    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:272:12)
```

but the problem the file is there any suggestion ?

Comment: Check the file access permissions.  You will get this message also when the process doesn't have access to the path.

Comment: Could you please specify your problem a bit more ? What are you trying to do ? On which platform ? etc.  | Might be helpful to solve your problem :)

Comment: @ChrisRoland I am using windows 10 , node 12.15 and when i am trying to do npm run deploy it rich to the package that minifying the images and it shows this error the package name is imagemin-cli

Comment: @Ezra all permissions are given

Comment: @AliMardini this might be helpful : https://github.com/imagemin/imagemin/issues/199